# can unkowns of a system of linear equations be looked at as unknown scalars of vector combination?

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm trying to gain a better understanding of how linear systems work. Given that Ax=b

A= [3 4 5] x= [x1, x2, x3] b = [2,4,7]   where x is a vertical column -since by definition the number of rows of A must equal the number of columns of B.- In vector form it could be written as 
x1(3)+ x2(4)+ x3(5)= (2,4,7). From this it appears that (3), (4), (5) are vectors and the variables are in fact scalars. Is this an accurate way of looking at a system? Please don't down vote.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, $A$ is a $1\times 3$ matrix and $x$ & $b$ are $3\times 1$ matrices.  Then the equation $Ax=b$ doesn't make sense.  In general if you have an $m\times n$ matrix times an $n\times p$ matrix your result will be an $m\times p$ matrix.

Comment: Also, for future reference to get a matrix such as $\pmatrix{1 & 2 & 3 \\ 4 & 5 & 6}$ you just have to type `$\pmatrix{1 & 2 & 3 \\ 4 & 5 & 6}$`.